# Как вывести содержимое всех файлов в папке в консоль

Tags: файлы, java

Не могу заставить BufferedReader прочесть весь набор файлов. Есть ли аналогичный способ вывода содержимого файлов?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DirectoryShow {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File f = new File("D:\\Files"); // current directory

        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader("D:\\Files");
             String line = null;
             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println(line);
             }
            System.out.print("     file:");
            System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Надо закрывать `BufferedReader`

Comment: Что значит не могу? Что конкретно у вас происходит (ошибка или еще что-то)? Обратите внимание на комментарий @Barmaley.

Comment: > `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader("D:\\Files");`

Вы имели в виду `new BufferedReader(file)`?

Answer (score 1):

У вас, как отметил [[@VlaD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd) код не работает, потому что вместо

```
new BufferedReader("D:\\Files")
```

нужно было написать

```
new BufferedReader(file)
```

А на счёт аналогичных способов, можно, например, использовать грязный хак со [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

```
File dir = new File("D:\\Files");
for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
    System.out.println("Content of " + file.getCanonicalPath() + ":");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file)).useDelimiter("\\A");
    if (scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
    }
}
//FileInputStream по-хорошему нужно бы закрыть, но можно оставить и так — в finalize() блоке он сам себя закрывает.
```